# XTypeOperators extension doesn't work as pragma

Tags: haskell, types

I'm using GHCi 7.0.3 with the following program that implements type-level list:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

data True
data False

-- List
data Nil
data Cons x xs

-- Type-level infix operator must begin with ':'
data x ::: xs
infixr 5 ::: -- set precedence level to 5 (tight)
```

It compiles, but when I test it with:

```
:t (undefined :: True:::Nil)
```

(what's the type of `undefined` when cast to type `True:::Nil`?) I get this error:

```
Illegal operator `:::' in type `True ::: Nil'
  Use -XTypeOperators to allow operators in types
```

And indeed, when I start GHCi with the flag

```
-XTypeOperators
```

I get the expected result:

```
(undefined :: True ::: Nil) :: True ::: Nil
```

My question is: Why doesn't the equivalent pragma work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
```

---

Edit: If pragmas don't extend to GHCi environment than I have another puzzle. I tried this program:

```
class And b1 b2 b | b1 b2 -> b where
    andf :: b1 -> b2 -> b

-- truth table
instance And True True True where andf = undefined
instance And True False False where andf = undefined
instance And False True False where andf = undefined
instance And False False False where andf = undefined
```

It required the following pragmas:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
```

But once compiled, I could use it in GHCi:

```
*Main> :t andf (undefined::True) (undefined::False)
          andf (undefined::True) (undefined::False) :: False
```

I guess in the list case the interpreter couldn't even parse the expression with type-level operator `:::`, whereas in the case of multiparameter classes the command line was parseable. But, come to think of it, GHCi performed type inference using multi-parameter classes and functional dependencies, didn't it? This type inference is done in GHCi, and not by calling some function in the compiled code, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The other answers are correct about enabling the extension in GHCi, either from the GHCi prompt or as a flag when starting GHCi. There is a third option, however--you can create a `.ghci` file that will be loaded and run every time you start GHCi, and use that to enable the extension automatically. Particularly for things like `TypeOperators`, where there's very little harm in having it enabled, it's nicely convenient.

For example, here's what mine looks like right now:

```
:set prompt "∀x. x ⊢ "
:set -XTypeOperators
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow
```

The `.ghci` file goes in whatever your system's standard location is for such files.

---

To answer your extended question: The code in question works in GHCi roughly because it would also work if used in another module, which imported the module using the pragmas but didn't enable them itself. GHC is more than capable of enabling extensions on a per-module basis, even when the exported definitions couldn't possibly make sense without an extension, or have inferred types that require it.

The distinction is a little fuzzy in GHCi because it also puts non-exported definitions from the module in scope, but in general anything that would work if used from another module will also work at the GHCi prompt.

Answer (score 7):

Your pragma is correct; the problem is that you're trying to use it from within GHCi, which doesn't inherit the extensions of the loaded module,<sup>1</sup> but *does* pass the options it's given to GHC to compile the files you list (which is why it has the same effect as the pragma).

You should keep the pragma, and either pass `-XTypeOperators` when you start GHCi, or enable it after loading the file as follows:

```
GHCi> :set -XTypeOperators
```

<sup>1</sup> Which could be very undesirable, and probably impossible in many cases, for e.g. loading compiled modules.

Answer (score 4):

The `LANGUAGE` pragma works for the source file, it is not propagated to the `ghci`-prompt. Since it is possible to have conflicting pragmas in multiple source files of a project, source pragmas cannot by default propagate to the `ghci`-prompt. It would be possible to have the pragmas from `*module`s effective at the prompt, I'm not sure, but I think it is pondered to implement that, anyway, so far, it's not implemented, so you need to set the extensions for `ghci` explicitly.