# GHC - Infixl declaration in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, accelerate-haskell

Hi I'm building my own version of a GPU programming Haskell DSL which is called **Accelerate**. The question is about the the `infixl` declaration:

Here is the code snippet:

```
infixl 3 :.
data tail :. head = tail :. head
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I think this snippet is quite simple and clear, but when I was trying to load this into ghci, it failed:

It reported:

```
Illegal declaration of a type or class operator ‘:.’
      Use TypeOperators to declare operators in type and declarations
```

Do you have any idea about this problem? The ghc version I'm using is:

```
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3
```

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to add a heterogeneous list type to haskell; That already exists in the HList package, and is also provided by GHC if you enable `DataKinds`. For example you could have a type `[Int,String,Int]` with kind `[*]`.

Comment: @Cubic Actually I dont really understand the meaning of that sentence ... However, I agree with your idea that this one is a heterogeneous list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
```

in your source file. That is what the error message says.
To use them in ghci, you have to enable there as well. See [XTypeOperators extension doesn't work as pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638035/xtypeoperators-extension-doesnt-work-as-pragma)

Comment: Oh it fixed! Thanks! But do you have any idea why this pragma should be there? I mean why ghc doesnt support it directly?

Comment: I did not read the [haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/), but I bet type operators are not included. Without pragmas, ghc complies to the standard.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's all about language standard... Thx

Comment: Where should infixr/infixl/infix declaration be put by convention? What if the operator is defined as part of a GADT? I see it could be put anywhere in the page?